# Manipulate color in VIM

Tags: vim, colors

In `hlsearch` mode, seems that you can set only one color.

Now I want to use a script to get multiple colors for multiple keywords, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. [Vim Tip 1572 ("Highlight multiple words")](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1572) and its [discussion page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Talk%3aHighlight_multiple_words) contains several methods/scripts.

You can also use the [Mark--Karkat](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Mark--Karkat) script.